# Разделить вывод в std::cout

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Написал функцию для вывода произвольного количества аргументов. Как передать в неё разделитель (пробел, например) так, чтобы вывод осуществлялся через разделитель, а не слитно?

```
template<typename... Args>
void print(const Args&... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
template<typename... Args>
void print(const Args&... args) {
    auto f{[](auto&& x) { cout << x << " "; }};
    (f(args),...);
}
```

Разделитель можно передать и как параметр:

```
template<typename... Args>
void print(const char * delim, const Args&... args) {
    auto f{[delim](auto&& x) { cout << x << delim; }};
    (f(args),...);
}
```

Чтоб не добавлять разделитель после последнего вывода - можно выкрутиться типа такого:

```
template<typename... Args>
void print(const char * delim, const Args&... args) {
    int count = sizeof...(args);
    auto f{[delim, &count](auto&& x) { cout << x; if (--count) cout << delim; }};
    (f(args),...);
}
```

(Думаю, можно и красивее... но, что в голову первым пришло :))

Comment: сильно красивее вряд ли выйдет, folding expressions достаточно убоги, чтобы не давать красивых решений.

Comment: @ixSci почему убоги? раньше же нужно было самому рекурсию делать, а теперь гораздо читабельнее

Comment: @hex, убоги потому что покрывают лишь малый процент случаев. Лучше чем то, что было, но хуже, чем можно было сделать. У них слишком жёсткие ограничения.